# Keyboard delay display/respond text or input lag

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

As of now I am using the screen keyboard.

I encountered this problem many times when updating my computer. Usually I will just restart and then my keyboard works fine but today I have already restarted it multiple times and it's still not working.

Upon searching I found some of these suggestions/answers found at Ask Ubuntu that are similar to my case but not same version of Ubuntu.

1. Install `xserver-xorg-input-all`
2. Check my settings/universal access then turn off sticky, slow and bounce keys (please see attached photo)
3. Switching to Mayland (you can find it when Ubuntu asks for your password. It take place when you restart/shutdown there’s an circle icon bottom right - just click it and you can find the Mayland)

Note that my laptop model is Dell Latitude E6540.

Comment: What is this switching to mayland

Comment: you can find it when ubuntu ask for your password it take place when you restart/shutdown
there’s an cicle icon bottom right just click it and you can find the mayland

Comment: Where are the attached photos/screenshots?

Comment: Hi the problem was already fixed and to be honest i don't know the reason,  it happens that when i check my keyboard time to time then suddenly it works properly , i dont know if it is bug or compatibility of my end. What i suggest is you should have portable keyboard for backup especially if you dont have backup computer or laptop. Thank you !